# Scrape a .txt file without delimiters into a JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop, txt

I'm trying to parse through a .txt file and convert it into a JSON object. This is what the .txt file looks like:

```
0000000159900000000000          John Smith              State Senator
0001001159915701270000DEM          Jill Booker             Governor
0002001159900000000000REP          James Williams          City Council
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
obj = {
        "name": State Senator,
        "reporting_units": [
            {
                "state_postal": "IL",
                "precincts_reporting": precincts_reporting,
                "total_precincts": precincts_total
                "candidates": [
                       {
                            "cand_name": "John Smith",
                            "cand_id": 0000000159900000000000
                       }
                ],

            }
        ],
        "name": Governor,
        "reporting_units": [
            {
                "state_postal": "IL",
                "precincts_reporting": precincts_reporting,
                "total_precincts": precincts_total
                "candidates": [
                       {
                            "cand_name": "Jill Booker",
                            "cand_id": 0001001159915701270000DEM
                       }
                ],

            }
        ],
        "name": City Council,
        "reporting_units": [
            {
                "state_postal": "IL",
                "precincts_reporting": precincts_reporting,
                "total_precincts": precincts_total
                "candidates": [
                       {
                            "cand_name": "James Williams",
                            "cand_id": 0002001159900000000000REP
                       }
                ],

            }
        ]
    }
```

This would be a relatively simple loop to create if the .txt file was delimited, but it is not. What I'd normally do is something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

def scraper():
    empty_list = []
    # define object (as above)
    with open('races.txt','r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for row in data:
            for item in row:
                cand_id = row[0]
                cand_name = row[1]
                name = row[2]
                # plug into object and append to list
scraper()
```

This issue right now is that `row[0]`, `row[1]` and `row[2]` are all 0 because I cannot split the row by some delimiter so it reads one character as one item. I don't know how to write it so that it reads an item, not a character, as an item. Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: You can split a row by "more than one space." Read about regular expressions.

Comment: Was trying to avoid regex but let me check this out. Thank you!

Comment: This worked brilliantly and was easy to incorporate, @DYZ! Thanks for your help.